# Align longtable header in landscape mode

Tags: latex, landscape, longtable

I have a really long and wide table in my latex document. I'm using the landscape with the longtable environment, but the header is not aligned with the columns in the tables.

```
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \caption{Long and wide table}\\
    \hline
    first & second & third} & fourth & fifth & sixth & 7th & 8th & 9th & 10th\\
\hline \hline
    \endhead
a & long & and & wide & table & very & long & and & very & wide \\
a & long & and & wide & table & very & long & and & very & wide \\
a & long & and & wide & table & very & long & and & very & wide \\
a & long & and & wide & table & very & long & and & very & wide \\
a & long & and & wide & table & very & long & and & very & wide \\
a & long & and & wide & table & very & long & and & very & wide \\
    \hline
    \label{tab:all_linreg}
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

is there a possibility to align the header with the columns?